# Parsing XML Fail

Tags: php, xml

I have an old Site that uses an XML Path, reads it and shows the desired content.

I used it now to create with it a new page, with a different XML-URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
  <item>
    <link>http://www.url.to/image.html</link>
    <itemname>Teapot</itemname>
    <city>Munich</city>
    <countryid>DE</countryid>
    <desc>
      <![CDATA[Here comes the Item Description]]>
    </desc>
    <imageurl>http://www.url.to/image.jpg</imageurl>
  </item>
</items>
```

Thats how the Items are created. Plain and simple.

The PHP Code that generates the Site now looks as simple as this:

```
<?php
    //###################Config Start#########################
    $maxAnzahl = 50;
    $zaehler = 4;
    //###################Config End#########################
        $feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.domain.tld/path-to-xml.php&filter1=rule1&filter2=rule2');
        $items = $feed->items;
        foreach ($items->item as $item) {
        if ($item->city == "Munich") {
        echo "<div class='4u'>";
        echo "<article class='box style2'>";
        echo "<a href='".link."' class='image featured' target='_blank'><img src='".imageurl."' alt=".itemname." /> </a>";
        echo "<h3><a href='".link."'>".itemname."</a></h3>";
        echo "</article>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
        $zaehler = $zaehler + 1;
        if ($zaehler == $maxAnzahl) {
            break;
        }
        }
?>
```

As from what i see it should be fine. but still, when i try to load the page, it tells me *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/testfolder/index.php on line 31* while Line 31 would be ***foreach ($items->item as $item) {***

Looks like i broke the original skript at some place, but i used already Winmerge to compare both files, and all the differences there are is that i kicked some variables out of the Config part, as they are of no use here anymore, different 'tags' that it needs to be looking for inside the xml url.

Would someone be able to make something out of it?

Kindly Caylean

Comment: Frankly, it looks fine to me, too.  SUGGESTION: Add "printf" debug statements.  For example `echo $feed->getName () . "<br/>"` (I suspect you'll get "items").  Or echo each subitem in `$feed->children()`.

Comment: Thanks but deep corrected it in the right way. As you can see in his answer. It was indeed a 'small' error that send my request to look one level too high... I shouldn' try to explain.. ;) I understood why it didn't work, but that is already all I understood ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.domain.tld/path-to-xml.php&filter1=rule1&filter2=rule2');
foreach($feed->item as $item){
```

root element `items` not exist in `$feed`. Also u must check if `$feed->item` is `array` or not.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
  <item>
    <link>http://www.url.to/image.html</link>
    <itemname>Teapot</itemname>
    <city>Munich</city>
    <countryid>DE</countryid>
    <desc>
      <![CDATA[Here comes the Item Description]]>
    </desc>
    <imageurl>http://www.url.to/image.jpg</imageurl>
  </item>
  <item>
    <link>http://www.url.to/image.html</link>
    <itemname>Teapot</itemname>
    <city>Munich</city>
    <countryid>DE</countryid>
    <desc>
      <![CDATA[Here comes the Item Description]]>
    </desc>
    <imageurl>http://www.url.to/image.jpg</imageurl>
  </item>
</items>
```

Right now `$feed->item` is `SimpleXMLElement`.

In this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>
  <item>
    <link>http://www.url.to/image.html</link>
    <itemname>Teapot</itemname>
    <city>Munich</city>
    <countryid>DE</countryid>
    <desc>
      <![CDATA[Here comes the Item Description]]>
    </desc>
    <imageurl>http://www.url.to/image.jpg</imageurl>
  </item>
</items>
```

`$feed->item` will be `array` or 2 `SimpleXMLElement`s.

Comment: Great, that works.... or not ;) .. The error is gone now. It shows the Content as i thought it would be correct, but it isn't. In my example you can see my mistake already; i thought i could 'call' the Link with a simple `.link.` as it was before `'".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$userid."'` baseURL isn't there anymore, as is userid. The i just realized .link. should be $event->profile->url or as with the new xml `$item->link` .. End now with _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$single' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'_ .. This whole xml and php isn't really my world :(

Comment: DONE! For some reason i needed to put the `$item->link` as `,$item->link,` .. and for some reason it was okay to keep the `$item->itemname` without the `,` as when i added the `,` to `$item->itemname` it would show ,Teapot, instead of just Teapot. Thank you very very VERY much. I am still bad with that xml stuff, but i might get the hang of it, at least the basics ;)